# 3D графики в Java Script

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Есть ли в js какая-нибудь библиотека, которая рисует такие графики?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел D3.js, но там в примерах не нашел такого

Answer (score 0):

**Three.js** И **Pixi.Js** могут все касательно 3D графики.

Все зависет от программиста и от его знаний определенной технологии.

Самый элементарный пример того чего может сделать **Three.js**

```js
let camera,
    scene,
    renderer,
    octree,
    geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 50 ),
    mesh,
    meshes = [],
    meshesSearch = [],
    meshCountMax = 100,
    radius = 500,
    radiusMax = radius * 10,
    radiusMaxHalf = radiusMax * 0.5,
    radiusSearch = 400,
    searchMesh,
    base = new THREE.Color( 0xff00ff ),
    found = new THREE.Color( 0x00ff00 ),
    adding = true,
    rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
    origin = new THREE.Vector3(),
    direction = new THREE.Vector3();
    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      scene.background = new THREE.Color("black");
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, radius * 100 );
      scene.add( camera );
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
      octree = new THREE.Octree( {
      undeferred: false,
      depthMax: Infinity,
      objectsThreshold: 8,
      overlapPct: 0.15,
      scene: scene
    } );
    searchMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( radiusSearch ),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00FF00, transparent: true, opacity: 0.4 } )
    );
    scene.add( searchMesh );
  }
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    modifyOctree();
    searchOctree();
    render();
    octree.update();
  }
function modifyOctree() {
  if ( adding === true ) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color( base ) } ) );
    mesh.position.set(
      Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf,
      Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf,
      Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf
    );
    octree.add( mesh );
    scene.add( mesh );
    meshes.push( mesh );
    if ( meshes.length === meshCountMax ) {
      adding = false;
    }
  } else { 
    mesh = meshes.shift();
    scene.remove( mesh );
    octree.remove( mesh );
    if ( meshes.length === 0 ) {
      adding = true;
    }
  }

}
function searchOctree() {
  let i, il;
  for ( i = 0, il = meshesSearch.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
    meshesSearch[ i ].object.material.color.copy( base );
  }
  searchMesh.position.set(
    Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf,
    Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf,
    Math.random() * radiusMax - radiusMaxHalf
  );
  origin.copy( searchMesh.position );
  direction.set( Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1, Math.random() * 2 - 1 ).normalize();
  rayCaster.set( origin, direction );
  meshesSearch = octree.search( rayCaster.ray.origin, radiusSearch, true, rayCaster.ray.direction );
  rayCaster.intersectOctreeObjects( meshesSearch );
  for ( i = 0, il = meshesSearch.length; i < il; i ++ ) {
    meshesSearch[ i ].object.material.color.copy( found );
  }
}
function render() {
  let timer = - Date.now() / 5000;
  camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 10000;
  camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 10000;
  camera.lookAt( scene.position );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/Octree.js"></script>
```